# Sqoop create job is complaining about the arguments

Tags: sqoop

When I run the below sqoop import job it's working perfectly fine.

```
    sqoop import -libjars ${JARS} --driver ${DRIVER}
 --connect ${URL} -m 1 --hive-overwrite --hive-import 
--hive-database ${Database} --hive-table Table 
--target-dir '/tmp/Table' --as-parquetfile 
--query "select cl1, c12, c13 from sourceSchema.sourceTable WHERE 1=1 AND \$CONDITIONS"
```

When I try to create the sqoop job for the same import its complaining that there is error in parsing the arguments

**Create sqoop job**

```
sqoop job --create SomeJobName  -- import -libjars ${JARS} 
--driver ${DRIVER} --connect ${URL} -m 1 
--hive-overwrite --hive-import 
--hive-database ${Database} 
--hive-table Table --target-dir '/tmp/Table' --as-parquetfile 
--query "select cl1, c12, c13 from sourceSchema.sourceTable WHERE 1=1 AND \$CONDITIONS"
```

Here is the error I'm getting :

```
 Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
    18/02/15 10:55:56 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.12.1
    18/02/15 10:55:57 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
    18/02/15 10:55:57 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -libjars
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by adding the `-libjars` argument in the generic arguments. Got to know by looking at the syntax  `sqoop job (generic-args) (job-args) [-- [subtool-name] (subtool-args)]` in [sqoop doc](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax_4)

```
sqoop job -libjars /var/lib/sqoop/some.jar,/var/lib/sqoop/some.jar--create SomeJobName  -- import
--driver ${DRIVER} --connect ${URL} -m 1 
--hive-overwrite --hive-import 
--hive-database ${Database} 
--hive-table Table --target-dir '/tmp/Table' --as-parquetfile 
--query "select cl1, c12, c13 from sourceSchema.sourceTable WHERE 1=1 AND \$CONDITIONS"
```